# How to set alternate row color for a given attached diagram

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Description** : In the below diagram a table consists of rows with expand window. The expand view details are also in a row. So, a single record kept in two rows. One row in main table and another row is while expanding. So, here we need to apply alternate row color for main table other than expanding rows. How we can apply alternate row color for main rows.

send css class for MVC

[image]

Comment: Please insert that image here, don't ask people to hop to external sites, what if that site goes down? This question may go for a toss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery (javascript) Method - Best for compatibility.**

In the example below the first `nth-child` filter selects every 4th item starting from the 1st. Then it filters every 4th item starting from the 3rd. This will work in pretty much every browser you throw at it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('tr')
        .filter(':nth-child(4n+1)').addClass("rowColor1")
    .end()
        .filter(':nth-child(4n+3)').addClass("rowColor2");

});
```

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/6r22F/1/

**Pure CSS Method - Best for speed and purity.**

A simpler method is to use CSS. It will be the fastest method and means you don't have script running unnecessarily. It may not work in older browsers though so check the browser stats for your user demographic.

```
tr:nth-child(4n+1) {
        background: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
tr:nth-child(4n+3) {
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

DEMO -

http://jsfiddle.net/f3hk8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
         $('table tr:nthchild(even)').css("background","red");
         $('table tr:nthchild(odd)').css("background","white");
```

Comment: This won't do what the author has asked. The author has asked that all rows be alternated apart from the ones that expand. First you need to find all the odd rows and alternate those. Also `nthchild` should be `nth-child` for it to work.